# ArcGIS Server 10 and Desktop 9.3 interoperability?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, interoperability

I want to install ArcGIS Server (AGS) 10 but our users only have ArcGIS Desktop 9.3.1.

So does Esri support:

- Access/use AGS services from 10 in 9.3.1?
- Manage (create services etc) AGS 10 from ArcCatalog 9.3.1?

I know you can use the web manager but our users are used to managing AGS from desktop.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot administer ArcGIS Server 10 using an older version of ArcGIS Desktop. See the [Migrating to 10](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#//00930000000n000000.htm) page in the help.

Also, if you upgrade any ArcSDE installations to ArcSDE 10, those servers will not support older desktop clients. See the [Product Compatibility Matrix](http://wikis.esri.com/wiki/display/SupportCenter/Product+Compatibility+Matrix) for ArcSDE.

However, consuming services between versions is generally supported. Some features at 10 may not be available at 9.X.

Answer (score 4):

a) Yes, I am doing that and you can view and zoom/pan etc (anything 9.3.1 allows a user to do).

b) No, You may only connect to the 10 server as a user, you may not manage except from a computer with version 10 of desktop installed.  You may manage a 9.3.1 server from a desktop with version 10.  I'm doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a post from the ESRI forums.  It suggests that you can consume services in 9.3.1, but you will not be able to create an administrative connection to the server.

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/16471-Can-ArcMap-9.3.1-consume-ArcGIS-Server-10-map-services-map-service-version-numbers

Answer (score 0):

I'd say avouid it like the plague as it's full of issues.  Just upgraded and having issues.  Just applying SP1 to the server and not a single desktop can cause issues.